# Find max based on 2 column and assign to another table's column

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables with following information.

```
id  name     date         time
1   jon    2019-08-06   13:45:00
2   clark  2019-08-03   21:20:00
3   mary   2019-08-04   16:12:00
```

Table B

```
id    date        time
1  2019-07-28   09:45:00
1  2019-07-31   12:45:00
1  2019-08-06   13:45:00
2  2019-08-02   21:20:00
2  2019-08-03   20:20:00
2  2019-08-04   21:20:00
2  2019-08-04   23:00:00
2  2019-08-04   01:20:00
3  2019-08-13   16:12:00
3  2019-08-13   19:12:00
3  2019-08-06   01:12:00
3  2019-08-06   08:12:00
3  2019-08-04   14:12:00
```

Required Resultset - Distinct A.* (given there are other tables in join so I only need resultset of distinct A set)

```
id  name     date         time
1   jon    2019-08-06   13:45:00
2   clark  2019-08-04   23:00:00
3   mary   2019-08-13   19:12:00
```

So I need max of date and time from table B and assign it to date and time field in table A.

Tried multiple things so far -

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN X ON A.id = X.id
WHERE x.col = 'A'
    AND (
        A.DATE
        ,A.TIME
        ) IN

SELECT MAX(TIME) AS TIME
FROM B
WHERE EVT_DT IN (
        SELECT MAX(DATE)
        FROM B
        WHERE A.id = 1
        )
```

This works but it doesn't assing date and time in table A:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN X ON A.id = X.id
WHERE x.col = 'A'
    AND CONCAT (
        A.DATE
        ,A.TIME
        ) =

SELECT MAX(DATE || TIME)
FROM B
WHERE A.id = 1 )
```

Comment: Hint - Use simple join, max time and group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum of the combination `date` and `time` in table `b` with `not exists` and then join to the table a:

```
select
  a.id, a.name, bb.date, bb.time
from a inner join (
  select b.* from b
  where not exists (
    select 1 from b as t
    where t.id = b.id and timestamp(t.date, t.time) > timestamp(b.date, b.time)
  )
) as bb
on bb.id = a.id;
```

I use the function [`timestamp()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/th/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000859.html) to compare date and time.

Comment: I am not sure if these works for me, Given I mentioned I only need the distinct resultset from table A given the whole application has a model class based on single table and it is being used many places. So Select A.* from (...) could be the only resultset.

Comment: Did you try it? From A you need only 2 columns and the other 2 with maximum date and time from B. This is what this code does

Comment: I did try it. It is failing for me complaining with -104 for end-of-statement where we give the alias b

Comment: I don't know if DB2 has any strange rule about aliases. Try my edited code.

Comment: Is the above code that you test or did you change it?

Comment: I changed it with actual col names and stuff. What I provided was simplified eg of my table. select A.car_init,A.car_numb,b.EVT_DT,b.EVT_TM from oy.TCAR_INVENTORY A inner join (select b.* from OY.TCAR_HISTORY b 
where not exists (select 1 from OY.TCAR_HISTORY as t where t.car_init = b.car_init and t.car_numb = b.car_numb and timestamp(t.EVT_DT, t.EVT_TM) > timestamp(b.EVT_DT, b.EVT_TM))) bb

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste problem. I forgot the ON clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: No worries I understand. I tried the updated one it runs but takes 12 seconds. I need something much lesser then that. But thank you for trying to help out.

Comment: The function timestamp() does not allow the use of indices (if any). If you had just 1 column for date and time in both tables then there would be no need to use a function and the query would execute faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc time desc) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id
where b.seqnum = 1
```